Why does statistical model over Cartesian product space yield likelihood for prediction of next element?
This is not a question about how to estimate likelihood, but rather about bridging the gap between intuition and theory.
Motivating setting
Let's say we observe a sample of 10 bits $\{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1\}$, and based on this we estimate $\mathbf{p}(x=1) = 0.5$. So given the 11th bit $x_{11}$, we know the likelihood that it is one is $0.5$.
Now more formally, let there be a vector $\mathbf{x}$, taking value in the Cartesian product sample space $\Omega^n$, where each $\Omega = \{0,1\}$. Now suppose the distribution is in the exponential family with sufficient statistic $\mathbb{\phi}(x) = x$, mean $\mu = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{p}}[\mathbb{\phi}(x)] = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and distribution of form $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x};\mu) = exp( \mathbf{x}'\mu + A(\mu) )$, where $A$ is the log partition function. After observing many examples of $\mathbf{x} \in \Omega^n$, what have we estimated? And what is the likelihood that a single bit is $1$ having observed examples from $\Omega^n$?
question
This is the part there's some mismatch between intuition and what is written above. Because the samples from $\Omega^n$ are n bit strings, but the expectation of the sufficient statistics of the samples (read the mean) is the likelihood that a single bit is 1. And yet the probability function $ \mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x};\mu)$ is really the likelihood a single $n$ bit string in $\Omega^n$ takes on any value. So for example if the distribution is uniform, then:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x};\mu) = \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{equation}
for every n-bit string. There is no way we can get $1/2$ from that, unless we are asking for the set of $n$-bit strings where 'some' of the bits are 1, and again assuming uniform distribution over all $n$-bit strings. And you certainly cannot write $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x}=1;\mu)$ based on that, because again the $\mathbf{p}$ here is measuring the sample space $\Omega^n$, not a single $\Omega$.
updates
There's a long thread below so some of the comments are copied here. The fundamental question here is when you receive an $n$-bit string, are you sampling once from $\{0,1\}^n$ or sampling n times from $\{0,1\}$. Because if it's the former, then you can define sufficient statistic and mean as $\mu = E[\phi(\mathbf{x})] = 1/n \sum_i^n x_i$. But then the $\sigma$-algebra would be defined over the product set $\{0,1\}^n$, so you cannot ask what is $P(\mathbf{x}=1)$, because $\mathbf{x}$ is an n-bit string, not a single bit. So then the question is that does the query $P(\{1\})$ reduce down to:
\begin{equation}
P(\{0\}_1 \times \{0,1\}_2 \times ... \times \{0,1\}_n) = 
P(\{0\}_1) \times P(\{0,1\}_2) \times .. \times P(\{0,1\}_n)
\end{equation}
But if you do this, you're still left to write $P(\{0,1\}_i)$, which is not modeled here.
Or we can say an n-bit string is sampling n times iid from $\{0,1\}$, I always thought it was this. In this case the sigma algebra is
$\sigma(\{0,1\}) = \{ empty-set, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\} \}$.
Then you can ask $P(x=1) = P(\{1\})$. But what is the sufficient statistic here? $E[\phi(x)] = 1/1 \cdot x$? That gives you either 0 or 1 as the mean.
additional reading about exponential family and sample space constructions that motivated my confusion

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WvdpFqptZk

page 18 on https://cba.mit.edu/events/03.11.ASE/docs/Wainwright.1.pdf



You can get $p(X_1 = 1) = \sum_{x_2, \dots, x_n \in {0, 1}}p(X_1 = 1, X_2 = x_2, \dots, X_n = x_n)$.

Ah so you take the distribution defined over the product sample space, and marginalize out the rest to get it for each one? could you expand the expression inside the sum a bit more? because it would seem like you still at some point need an expression $P(X_i = 1)$ inside that sum, which we do not have. We only have the joint distribution $P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ... X_n = x_n)$

@Kakashi or is it more or less what i said, which you have restated from that sum. Which is that to get $P(X_i = 1)$, it's actually defined over the space ${1}_1 \times {0,1}_2 \times ... \times {0,1}_n$, which is what the expression you stated above is stating.

I'm saying that a model for the joint likelihood leads to distributions for each variable. You can estimate parameters like $P(X_1 = 1; \mu)$ however you like.

@Kakashi in the setting above i assume you're only given n-bit strings, not one bit. The original comment makes more sense, so you're measuring $P({1}_1 × {0,1}2 ×...× {0,1}) = (2^{n-1})/(2^n) = 1/2$, is that what you were trying to say?

and why does "joint likelihood leads to distributions for each variable". Take a simpler  example, if i estimated the probability of a dice and a coin to get their joint distribution, is it possible to recover the probablity of each face of the die, and the bias of the coin from the joint? It is the law of total probabilty that you wrote right.

It isn't about estimating, it's about modelling. A model for the distribution of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ entails a model for $X_1$ by marginalization.

@Kakashi so in the context of the product space why is that the model for the joint entail model for $X_1$? The measure is defined over the sigma algebra of the cartesian product space right? But no where in that sigma algebra is there the set ${0}$,but there is the set ${1,0,0,0,...}$ and so on.

To add to what I was saying before. The sigma algebra defines the set of allowed inputs to the measure $P$ right? If I now input $P({1})$ into a measure that's defined for $n$-bit strings (n>0), then the $P$ function should return undefined.

$P(X_1 \in A) = P(X_1 \in A, X_2 \in \mathbb{R}, X_3 \in \mathbb{R}, \dots)$.

@chibro2. you have to define the events you are interested in applying the measure to. Are they "n-bit" strings or 1-bit" strings ?  If they are 1 bit, then the  resulting sigma field and the induced probability measure is a lot different than if they are n-bit.

@markleeds yes that's exactly my confusion, reading page 18 of (https://cba.mit.edu/events/03.11.ASE/docs/Wainwright.1.pdf), he defines exponential family as taking input of random vector from sample space that is a Cartesian product. So I'm really asking what does he mean here? Because an n-bit string could be one sample $\mathbf{x}$ from $\Omega^n$, or sampling n times from one $\Omega$. But if you sample once, how can you compute the sufficient statistic $\phi(x) = \sum_{i}^n x_i$ ?

@markleeds I always thought an n-bit string is sampling n times from one $\Omega ={0,1}$, however if you apply this then you every sufficient statistic is just $\phi(x_i) = 1$ or $\phi(x_i) = 0$. So then you apply Wainwright's def of sampling  one $n$-bit string, then $\phi$ can be computed. However the sigma algebra is now defined on $\Omega^n$, so you can only input product sets like $P({1}_1 ...\times ..{0,1}_n)$, you cannot input just a single set $P({0}$.

@chibro2: I don't have time to read the whole thing but, based on page 18, it looks you are correct  in that, in this particular problem, one $\omega$ represents the $n$ bits. Let me go back and read your question carefully and try to make heads or tails out of your specific confusion beyond that. I don't know if I'll be able to.

@chinro2: Like I said, I don't have time to read the whole thing but I think the harmless assumption is that, after you sample once, ( assuming you only sample once ), you have the vector $\mathbf{x}$ but this doesn't stop you from having the individual $x_i$. So, it's okay to sample "once" because you still have the individual $x_i$ scalars. That's the only thing I can come up with as far as why it's okay ?  Maybe there's a deeper answer but I tend to doubt it. Just assume that they like to work in vectors and then convert back.

@markleeds i found the answer here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/.  It's the notation that's confusing. $\Omega$ is actually the triple $\Omega = (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, so it's a product of the triple, not the elementary events.

chibro2: I'll read the link. thanks for it and I'm glad its cleared up for you. ( maybe me too ? ).
